# How to pass Android Byte [] array from OnPreviewFrame to Zxing Decode(byte[])

Tags: android, arrays, android-camera, zxing.net

When I am accessing the byte array from the camera preview, and I try passing it to Zxing's Decode(byte[]) method it says the source must not be null. I tried converting this byte array to base64 and seeing what the image looks like,  but the image is null as well. So I'm wondering what format the Byte[] array is in, and how can I convert to JPG or a usable format for Zxing? The camera preview is working fine, and the OnPreviewFrame(byte[], Camera) method is being called every frame so I'm not sure why the byte[] image is blank? I've attached my code below.

```
BarcodeReader mBarcodeReader = new BarcodeReader();
    public void OnPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Android.Hardware.Camera camera)
    {
        
        if (data != null && camera != null)
        {
            try
            {
                
                var result = mBarcodeReader.Decode(data);
                if (result != null)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(result.Text);
                    var barcodeScannedObject = new Models.BarcodeScannedObject()
                    {
                        Code = result.Text,
                        Imgsrc = Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(data)),
                        ImageBytes = data,
                        Result = result,

                    };

                    // Send this info
                    Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Send(barcodeScannedObject, "ios-barcode");

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }

        }

    }
```